# Jquery responsive navbar that collapses on menu item click or menu button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

i am building a responsive navbar that is fixed to the top.
I got it working so that if you click the menu icon the navigation slides up and down using jQuery's [.slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/). And also slides up when you click a menu item in the dropdown navigation.

```
var toggle = false;

$(document).ready(function () {

    "use strict";

    $("#menu").click(function () {

        if (!toggle) {
            $(".nav-menu").slideDown(function () {
                $(this).toggleClass("nav-expanded").css('display', '');
            });
            toggle = !toggle;
            $("a.menu-link").click(function () {
                $(".nav-menu").slideUp(function () {
                    $(this).toggleClass("nav-expanded").css('display', '');
                });
                toggle = !toggle;
            });
        } else {
            $(".nav-menu").slideUp(function () {
                $(this).toggleClass("nav-expanded").css('display', '');
            });
            toggle = !toggle;
        }
    });
});
```

You can see a [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1npmtzvu/3/) here.

However the problem is this: The menu button toggles the sliding as it should but clicking the menu items only slides the menu up once. After that the menu button still works but the sliding via click on menu item doesn't.

Thanks for all help in advance.

Comment: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1npmtzvu/6/) Updated Demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your JS a little bit:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    "use strict";

  $('#menu').click(function(e){
  var navMenu = $(".nav-menu");
    if($(this).hasClass('nav-expanded')){
        navMenu.stop(true,false).slideUp();
    } else {
        navMenu.stop(true,false).slideDown();
    }

    $(this).toggleClass('nav-expanded');

  });

  $(".nav-menu ul li").click(function(e){
    var target = $(e.currentTarget);
    var menu = $('#menu');

    menu.trigger('click');    
  });

});
```

[Link to fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/Joel_Jaun/6svkur3j/)

Comment: Thank you very much! I was working on this for far longer than i am able to admit. Now it works as intended!